# pnp PowerShell script to add all list columns as index

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp-powershell

Can I write a PnP PowerShell which get all the list columns and add them as index? skipping the fields which cannot be indexed, such as Multiple line of? or choice which allow multiple selection?

Thanks

Comment: You can add maximum 20 indexes per list. So, if you have 20+ columns which can be indexed, you will have to manually specify which columns to index.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MicrosoftMVP all my lists have less than 20 columns, so this is not any issue.. but not sure how i can get all the list's columns and add the ones which are applicable to be indexed?

Comment: Get all list columns using [Get-PnPField](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPField.html) then add indexing for columns by following [this article](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/07/sharepoint-online-add-indexed-column-using-powershell.html). Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MicrosoftMVP but how i can know if the column is eligible to be indexed or now?

Comment: Here are the list of [supported column types](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/add-an-index-to-a-list-or-library-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0) and you can get column type information while using `Get-PnPField`. Then you can match the column type with supported list columns in your code before indexing the column.